# Correcting authors' typos in excerpt from papers

Tags: discussion, support, editing, references, papers

In [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179321/computing-covariance-matrix-from-the-given-variances/) the correctly copied excerpt from the  [paper used](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/papers/CSD-04-1330.pdf) reproduces a typo that would make the findings of the paper invalid. The correct simulation setting is found in the [paper cited within the paper used](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/spc_jcgs.pdf). (*It is clear that one cannot use the variance in the  paper the OP uses, an error variance of $300$ instead of $1$ would invalidate any findings.*) 
Should we fix the excerpt presented and break compatibility with the original text or not? I checked other version of the paper used by the OP ([here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0406021v3.pdf) and [here](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/2628-a-direct-formulation-for-sparse-pca-using-semidefinite-programming.pdf)) and all have the same typo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My thoughts first on what one does if one is writing a question:

- If you're quoting a paper, *you should quote it verbatim* and then explain why the original is wrong (including quoting the correct statement from the earlier reference). If you really want to make it obvious, include "[*sic*]" inside the quote, immediately after the part that's wrong to highlight that's what the original *says*, which will alert people to the fact that it probably isn't right, and have them looking for the explanation of the issue.
- If you're not making a direct quote you don't necessarily need to give the wrong statement but you should probably mention the issue to save people some confusion.

Now, if one is pondering editing a question:

- I think the same conventions apply, except I'd lean toward doing it in comments and giving the OP the opportunity to correct their own post first.

Comment: Thank you your input. Yes, I am clearly concerned for the situation one quotes a paper verbatim. In an indirect quote it is a no-brainer that we would not give the wrong statement. / I followed your advice and made a comment about it.